# Why can I not establish an SSH/SFTP connection from my Windows 8.1 computer?

Tags: wireless-networking, ssh, windows-8.1, ftp, sftp

I'm on a windows 8.1, 64bit machine. I cannot get a connection vis SSH or SFTP. Yesterday I was connecting without issue.

I have tried using: Aptana, WinSCP, Putty and FileZilla. I cann connect to normal FTP, HTTP and HTTPS but not SSH or SFTP.

I have two wireless broad band connection coming in through NetGear routers and I have tried both routers with the same failure.

I am trying to connect to multiple servers from multiple hosting companies and getting the same failure on all of them. They are all accounts that I frequently access via SSH and or SFTP. and I accessed some of them yesterday.

My hosts file is as it always is. I checked and there are no changes to it.

I am using Windows Firewall and all of these apps are authorized. I am also using Avast. I turned both of these off and I still cannot make a connection.

Comment: Just use PuTTY for SSH... What is the failure? Can you SSH to `sdf.org` and get a log in prompt?

Comment: I am using putty for SSH, I also use Aptana and Filezilla for SFTP. The failure is a Error: Could not connect to server Connection timed out.

Comment: No. I cannot get a prompt at sdf.org. It is the same as with all others. I get a "Network error: Connection timed out" just as I do with any other server I try to SSH into.

Comment: Is it possible that your internet provider is blocking SSH?

Comment: #ekaj, it turns out there was a problem with the wireless network adapter that was fixed automatically when I ran a troubleshooter in the Network and Internet section of the Control Panel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This did, ultimately, turn out to be a case of my ISP blocking port 22 on me. They would block port 22 if the number of requests exceeded a certain level in a certain period, and the block would last for about an hour, so it kept seeming like I had fixed the problem, but it was just the block lifting.

The final solution was for my ISP to whitelist me for port 22, and I've never had a problem since.

I apologize that I failed to post this for so long.

<del>Well, I still don't now what was actually wrong, but I found a troubleshooter link in [Control Panel\Network and Internet\Network and Sharing Center].</del>

I ran the troubleshooter with automatically fix problems turned on and it came back stating that a problem in the WiFi adapter had bee fixed. I opened putty and got an immediate log in prompt.

Comment: Please Accept your answer: it'll help people know that you've truly found the fix to your problem!